# Make a valid Probability Density Function

Tags: probability

I understand that a valid PDF must

1. $f(x)\ge 0 $ for all $x$,

and

2. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\, dx =1$.

But I got this question: X and Y are two random variables with joint PDF:

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}x^2+cy & x\ge0,y\le1  \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Now I need to find "c" so that it's a valid PDF.

I can't kinda get my head around with this two-variable PDF. Could anyone please give me a hint?

Thanks very much!

Comment: As written, $\iint_{\mathbb R^2}f(x,y)dxdy=\infty $.

Comment: You want $c$ such that $\iint_{\mathbb R^2}f(x,y)dxdy=1$ though in this particular case $x\ge 0,y\le 1$ does not allow that.  If you had $0 \le x \le 1$ and $0 \le y \le 1$ then you would want  $\frac13+\frac c2=1$ and so $c=\frac43$

Comment: I think you are right @Henry! I think I misunderstood the question and it should be $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $0 \leq y \leq 1$ (the original question is written in a very confusing way). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem in your question. Like Surb suggested, the integral $\iint f(x,y)dxdy$ is infinite regardless the value of $c$, hence impossible to be a PDF. Maybe the question provides a wrong domain?

Comment: Thank you kelvin hong 方, as I commented above, like @Henry said, the condition should be 0≤≤1 and 0≤≤1. And thus c = 4/3. Sorry about the confusion.